# How to access loopback model inside another model without having declare that model in each method

Tags: loopback

I understand how to get a reference of Model2 inside Model1 my question is can you do this on a module level and not method level.

**Example:**

```
var app = require('../../server/server.js');

module.exports = function (user) {
  user.method1 = function (id, role, next) {
  var Role = app.models.role;
  }
}
```

The above works fine but if I had method2 and method3 that also needed access to Role are there any other options besides declaring  var Role = app.models.role; in each method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
module.exports = function (user) {
  var app;
  var Role;

  user.on('attached', function setupApp(receivedApp) {
    app = receivedApp;
    Role = app.models.role;
  });

  user.method1 = function (id, role, next) {
    // use Role here
  }
}
```